# Sort DataTable based on two column, whichever greater

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda

I have a table like (date in mm/DD/yyyy format)

```
ID  blocked_date  admincanceldate
.................................
1   06/06/2017    08/06/2017
1   07/06/2017    DBNULL
1   04/06/2017    09/06/2017
1   DBNULL        03/06/2017
1   02/06/2017    01/06/2017
```

I want to sort in based on following condition,

If blocked_date is greater than admincanceldate then by blocked_date else admincanceldate(greater date), then by lesser date.

I am using `VB.Net` and my query is

```
dtCorporateDetails = dtCorporateDetails.AsEnumerable() _
                     .OrderByDescending(If((ConvertToDate(Function(c) c.Field(Of Object)("admincanceldate"))) > (ConvertToDate(Function(c) c.Field(Of Object)("blocked_date"))), (ConvertToDate(Function(c) c.Field(Of Object)("admincanceldate")))), (ConvertToDate(Function(c) c.Field(Of Object)("blocked_date")))) _
                     .ThenByDescending(If((ConvertToDate(Function(c) c.Field(Of Object)("admincanceldate"))) > (ConvertToDate(Function(c) c.Field(Of Object)("blocked_date"))), (ConvertToDate(Function(c) c.Field(Of Object)("blocked_date"))), (ConvertToDate(Function(c) c.Field(Of Object)("admincanceldate"))))) _
                     .CopyToDataTable()
```

and

```
    Private Function ConvertToDate(ByVal obj As Object) As Nullable(Of Date)
        Dim retDate As Date = Nothing

        If Not IsDBNull(obj) Then
            retDate = CDate(obj)
        End If

        Return retDate
    End Function
```

but I am getting an error

> Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) in extension method 'Public
>   Function OrderByDescending(Of TKey)(keySelector As System.Func(Of
>   System.Data.DataRow, TKey), comparer As
>   System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of TKey)) As
>   System.Data.OrderedEnumerableRowCollection(Of System.Data.DataRow)'
>   defined in 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions' cannot be
>   inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly
>   might correct this error.

how can I resolve it?

tagged c# because I can convert it from c# also.

Comment: I think the problem is that you're trying to use the VB.NET `If` intrinsic as the sorting function in `OrderByDescending`, but this does not work with VB's type deduction.  Suggest to try putting it within a lambda function instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `OrderBy` function takes a delegate or lambda function, not an expression. The `ConvertToDate` function takes an expression, not a lambda function.

Removed unnecessary parentheses and use of `.Field(Of Object)` which isn't helpful (could also be `c.Field(Of DateTime)("...")`).

```
dtCorporateDetails = dtCorporateDetails.AsEnumerable() _
             .OrderByDescending(Function(c) If(ConvertToDate(c("admincanceldate")) > ConvertToDate(c("blocked_date")), ConvertToDate(c("admincanceldate")), ConvertToDate(c("blocked_date"))) _
             .ThenByDescending(Function(c) If(ConvertToDate(c("admincanceldate")) > ConvertToDate(c("blocked_date")), ConvertToDate(c("blocked_date")), ConvertToDate(c("admincanceldate")))) _
             .CopyToDataTable()
```